# Spring batch IllegalStateException for updates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm fairly new to Spring, and coding in general. I want to build an application from which a user can update existing records in a database from a CSV file. I'm using spring batch to do so, but when I execute the test, I get the famous:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).
```

If I remove the `@Transactional`, I get this error instead:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE com.example.testApp.Models.Person p SET p.address = p.address, p.country = p.country, p.cellphone = p.cellphone, p.city = p.city, p.phone = p.cellphone, p.email = p.email, p.age = p.age WHERE p.pplId IN (:ids_0, :ids_1, :ids_2, :ids_3, :ids_4, :ids_5, :ids_6, :ids_7, :ids_8, :ids_9, :ids_10)]
```

I've looked around some other solutions here, but they don't seem to work for what I want to do. I'm aware that hibernate supports batch updates, but again, I'm not sure how to make it work with what I already have.

Here's my test class (obviously with just the method I've been having problems with):

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class PersonTests {

    @Autowired
    private PeopleRepository peopleRepository;

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job peopleInsertJob; //Separate job for inserting from a CSV file

    @Autowired
    Job peopleUpdateJob;

@Order(4) //executes after the insert from CSV test, for obvious reasons.
@Test
public void updateRecordsFromCsvFile() throws Exception {

        Map<String, JobParameter> maps = new HashMap<>();
        maps.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        JobParameters parameters = new JobParameters(maps);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(peopleUpdateJob, parameters);

        assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getStatus().name());
    }
}
```

Here's my Batch configuration file for the update:

```java
 @Bean
    public Job peopleUpdateJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                                  StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                  ItemReader<Person> itemReaderForUpdate,
                                  ItemProcessor<Person, Person> itemProcessor,
                                  @Qualifier("DBPeopleUpdater") ItemWriter<Person> itemUpdater)
    {

        Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("ETL-file-load")
                .<People, People>chunk(100)
                .reader(itemReaderForUpdate)
                .processor(itemProcessor)
                .writer(itemUpdater)
                .build();

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("ETL-Load")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }
 @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader itemReaderForUpdate() throws Exception
    {
        FlatFileItemReader<Person> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

        flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/CSV/TestFilePeople-UpdateBatch.csv"));

        flatFileItemReader.setName("PeopleCSV-Update-Reader");
        flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<Person> lineMapper()
    {
        DefaultLineMapper<Person> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
        lineTokenizer.setNames("Id","lastname", "lastname2", "firstname",
                "midname","phone", "cellphone", "email", "status", "address", "city", "region", "country");

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Person.class);

        defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        return defaultLineMapper;
    }
```

This is the ItemWriter I'm using for the update:

```java
@Component
public class DBPeopleUpdater implements ItemWriter<Person> {

    @Autowired
    PeopleRepository peopleRepository;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Person> list) throws Exception
    {
        List<String> pplIds = new ArrayList<>();
        for(People p : list)
        {
            pplIds.add(p.getpplId());
        }

        peopleRepository.updatePersonsByIdIsIn(pplIds);

    }
}
```

This is the method that I'm using from my PeopleRepository. It's the only method I have. My repository is extends CrudRepository:

```java
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Person p SET p.address= p.address, p.country = p.country," +
            "p.cellphone = p.cellphone, p.city = p.city, p.phone = p.cellphone," +
            "p.email = p.email, p.status = p.status WHERE p.pplId IN :ids")
    List<Person>updatePersonsByPplIdIsIn(List<String> ids);
```

I'm mapping my Person class as an entity that connects to a PostgreSQL database table. I don't have any local sql files in my project. I have no other tables in the database.

If it's not possible to solve this using spring batch, if you could guide me towards jpa/hibernate resources I could use to understand how to solve this problem, I would really appreciate it.

**EDIT**
Here's the code for the entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "people", schema = "example_schema")
public class Person  {
    @NonNull
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ppl_id")
    private String pplId;

    @Column(name = "ppl_last_name")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "ppl_sec_last_name")
    private String lastname2;

    @Column(name = "ppl_first_name")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "ppl_mid_name")
    private String midname;

    @Column(name = "ppl_phone_no")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "ppl_cell_no")
    private String cellphone;

    @Column(name = "ppl_corp_email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="ppl_status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name="ppl_address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="ppl_city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="ppl_region")
    private String region;

    @Column(name="ppl_country")
    private String country;

    //Default constructor
    public Person()
    {
        super();
    }

public Person(@NonNull String pplId, String lastname, String lastname2, String firstname, String midname, String phone, String cellphone, String email, String status, String address, String city, String region, String country) {
        this.pplId = pplId;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.lastname2 = lastname2;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.midname = midname;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.cellphone = cellphone;
        this.email = email;
        this.status = status;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.region = region;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getPplId() {
        return pplId;
    }

    public void setWrkId(String pplId) {
        this.pplId = pplId;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getLastname2() {
        return lastname2;
    }

    public void setLastname2(String lastname2) {
        this.lastname2 = lastname2;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getMidname() {
        return midname;
    }

    public void setMidname(String midname) {
        this.midname = midname;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getCellphone() {
        return cellphone;
    }

    public void setCellphone(String cellphone) {
        this.cellphone = cellphone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
```

Comment: Please share the Entity class and if feasible post the code in github will reply in 1 hour

Comment: I added the entity. Sorry for the lateness.

Comment: @Vant0ria Did you get any workaround on it ? , I am having the same issue on batch processing testcases